# How to judge the Mathematical Model in Image Processing

Tags: image-processing

To remove the noise from the image, we base on some mathematical model(minimizing the energy functional).
**Q**: For different models **A** and **B**(different functionals), How can we say which one is better in math. language?

e.g. in R.O.F. model people minimize the functional $\int_\Omega\sqrt{u^2_x+u_2_y}$ in $L^1$ norm, why it is better than model to minimize the $\int_\Omega(u_{xx}+u_{yy})^2$ in $L^2$, with the same constraint conditions?

Is this because that $L^2\subset L^1$?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question. (Which is also why the math stuff doesn't render)